# scp command to copy files from remote to local host returns error

Tags: file-transfer, scp, jsch

I need to copy/transfer some files between different machines over the same network. After doing some reading and search, I thought trying out Java's `jsch` may be a good option. The bitter fact is probably that no good documentation is available for the jsch perhaps. But then there aren't any other options that I know of.

To implement the file transfers, I picked up two machines on the same network, say host1 (server) where in I installed `sshd server`, is up and running and I am able to connect to it using putty. Second machine, say host2 (client/local). I installed sshd here as well.

Now I tried copying a file 'test.txt' on desktop of host1 (server) to host2 (client) by running following command in putty after connecting to host1 -

`scp admin@host1:test.txt /c`

But it returns the following error -

```
'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought to try in putty first and then implement in java.
I am working on jsch/ssh for the first time, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to `scp` something from Windows, then why not simply use `pscp` to achieve this?

You can download it from the `PuTTy` website.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

If you want to use it in a Java program, then here is an example: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html

Comment: I downloaded the putty from there only...but scp command doesnt seem to work after I connect to remote windows 7 machine which is running sshd server using putty as well. mkdir command did work.

Comment: did you also download `pscp.exe`?

Comment: oops...my bad...now I downloaded pscp.exe. But just wondering how to go about it?

Answer (score 6):

You could install git for windows ( http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ ). 
Git for windows includes ssh and scp which you can access when using a git bash window.

Then you can use git for source control as well! :-)

Comment: In a git bash window ,  it  can scp file from  winodows host to linux  host ;  how  does scp file from  linux host  to  a git bash window?

Comment: You just reverse the scp command. Instead of `scp localhost-path user@remote-host:/remotehost-path` you do `scp user@remote-host:/remotehost-path localhost-path`

Comment: Thanks ,@ Keith John Hutchison ; but  i  use `scp   linux-file  user@WINDOWS-HOST-IP:/windows-path`  in a  linux host, it not work. I got an error: `ssh: connect to host WINDOWS-HOST-IP port 22: Connection refused
lost connection` , can i  scp file  from linux host to a git bash window in  a linux host ?

Comment: git for windows includes scp and ssh.  You're looking for sshd on windows. See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server which I found from searching with https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sshd+windows&atb=v110-5_b&ia=web

Comment: Thanks for your advice ,@Keith John Hutchison.

Answer (score 2):

```
locate scp
```

To see if you actually have it.

Comment: even locate didnt work :(. I tried mkdir and a directory got created on remote. Not sure why the other commands are not working.

Comment: Yes...Windows 7 on both the machines.

Comment: Then i would go with Charles Boyd advice.